# how to avoid duplicates in this case

Tags: prolog

I have now this working as I want it :

```
male(roelof).
male(mans). 
male(ronald).
male(jan).

female(chantal).
female(marie).
female(gerda).
female(dagmar).
female(denise).
female(kimberly).

parent(mans,gerda).
parent(mans,roelof).
parent(marie,gerda).
parent(marie,roelof).
parent(dagmar,denise).
parent(dagmar,kimberly).
parent(ronald,denise).
parent(ronald,kimberly).
parent(chantal,tamara).
parent(roelof,tamara).
parent(jan,chantal).
parent(jan,dagmar).

% Looks for the father of a child. Gives the name if found. 
% if no father is  found then it gives false
father_child(Child) :-
parent(Father, Child),
 male(Father).

% Looks for the mother of a child. Gives the name if found. 
% if no mother is  found then it gives false
mother_child(Child) :-
parent(Mother, Child),
female(Mother).

% Looks if two person has the same father. 
% Gives true if a person is a father of both persons 
% Gives false if no person is a father of both persons.
same_father(Child, Sibling) :-
  parent(Father,Child),
  parent(Father,Sibling),
  male(Father).

% Looks if two person has the same mother. 
% Gives true if a person is a mother of both persons 
% Gives false if no person is a mother of both persons.
same_mother(Child, Sibling) :-
  parent(Mother,Child),
  parent(Mother,Sibling),
  female(Mother).

% Looks if there are siblings of a person. 
% Persons are siblings if they have the same father or
% if they have the same mother and not the same father.
siblings(X,Y) :-
       (   same_father(X, Y),
            X \= Y
        ;   same_mother(X, Y),
        \+ same_father(X, Y)
    ).

% Displays the output of siblings(X,Y) and takes care that 
% there are no duplicates.
display_siblings(Person) :-
      findall(Person - Y, (siblings(Person,Y), Y @< Person), Sibs),
      display_the_siblings(Sibs).

% Display a message if there are no siblings found. 
display_the_siblings([]) :-
       write('Er zijn geen zussen/broers bekend').

display_many([]).
display_many([H|T]):-
        writeln('Many elements '-H), display_many(T).

display_the-siblings([X]):- better_display([X]),!.
display_the_siblings([H|T]):- better_display([H|T]).

better_display([X]):-
    writeln('Single Element '-X).
better_display([X,Y|T]):-
    writeln('Many elements '-X), display_many([Y|T]).
```

But in this case display_siblings(Kimberly) is false because `kimberly @< denise` is failing.
Do I turn the rule so `Y @< Person` then `display_siblings(kimberly)` works but `display(gerda)` is failing.

Anyone a idea to get out of this mess ?

Roelof

Comment: it is in the code part. I think you have to scroll a little

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
apropos(setof).
apropos(findall).
apropos(member).
```

A combination of these can remove dulicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
display_siblings(Person) :-
    setof(Pair, (siblings(Person,Y), sib_pair(Person, Y, Pair)), Sibs),
    display_the_siblings(Sibs).

sib_pair(Person, Sib, Person-Sib) :-
    Person @< Sib.
sib_pair(Person, Sib, Sib-Person) :-
    Person @> Sib.
```